# How to log request and response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serilog

I have a lot of web Apis and I have to log every requests and responses but the condition is - some of the fields should be masked before logging.

Please help to achieve this.

Comment: Please write code to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

There are some helpful addons to destructure using a context https://github.com/destructurama

And here is some example of configuration:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Destructure.ByIgnoringProperties<YourClass>(x => x.SensitiveData)
    .CreateLogger()
```